# Why can I not connect to an IP with Port in WebKit / WebView?

Tags: swift, xcode, ip, port

I try to make a small iOS App which should open a single page app and then shows the content of a web site which is only accessible through an IP with Port

The code works with a standard URL like https://www.google.com but not with e.g. https://565.346.49.86:10000.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://***.***.4*.*6:10000")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

        webView.load(request)
    }
}
```

I expect a login form of my home server.

Comment: did you test your URL from a browser on the same machine to verify the IP address +port are valid and have a server listening?

Comment: @m0bl: yes I did. I can open the URL with the port with Safari on any device.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me when make the URL like this https://565.346.49.86:10000/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of the author. The issue is not the format of the url.